# How to upload file with model with ASP.NET Core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to make a small upload file api by using ASP.NET Core 1.0.
I have a model which I took from an MVC5 application:

```
public class RoomModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make a function like :

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public IActionResult Upload(List<RoomModel> rooms)
{
       // Check and upload file here.
       // Save parameter to database.
}
```

In my MVC5, it is OK with HttpPostedFileBase , but in ASP.NET Core, I don't know how to archive with the same result.

Can anyone help me please ?
Thank you.

P/S: I've searched for tutorials like this but found nothing. Every tutorial I've read is only about get key-value parameters , no tutorial is about placing information in a model like this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found this post :

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/288/uploading-files-with-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc

From this post, my RoomModel will be like this :

```
public class RoomModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

So, as my current knowledge, IFromFile replaces HttpPostedFileBase, and the step handling files is the same as HttpPostedFileBase.

Comment: That answer is for .NET Core, but your question was asking about Web Api 2 which is .NET Framework. This should not be the correct answer.

Comment: Oops, sorry. My title wasn't correct :( . At that time I was asking about asp.net core